# How can I make string upper and lower

Tags: python, string

I want to make function which make upper string to lower and lower string to upper.(one by one)
Code was like below.

```
def Upper_lower(words):

  for i in range(len(words)):
    if words[i].isupper() == True:
      words[i] = words[i].lower()
     
    else:
      words[i] = words[i].upper()

  return words

Upper_lower('AAABBBcccddd')
```

---

The answer was 'aaabbCCCDDD'
But I got error like this.

[image]

How can I fix this code?

Comment: use builtin function it can easily do that within 1 line

Comment: Do you have to make your own function? Because there is `'AAABBBcccddd'.swapcase()` that does exactly that.

Comment: As to why your error happens, you cannot change the string `words` by doing `words[i] = ... `. You need to change it to a list and turn it back into a string using `''.join()` afterwards, but normally it's better to use built-in functions if available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Manipulate your code like following if you don't want to use inbuilt function "swapcase"

```
def Upper_lower(words):
    res =""
    for i in words:
        if i.isupper() == True:
            res =res+i.lower()
        else:
            res =res+i.upper()

    return res

print(Upper_lower('AAABBBcccddd'))
```

else use this  one

```
def swap(s):
    return (s.swapcase())

str1 ='AAABBBcccddd'
swap(str1)
```